# How to get the Default Calendar in Android using the Expo SDK Calendar API?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-calendar

**SOLVED: Used await and a variable to store the promise.**

I am trying to insert an event into the default calendar on an android device using react-native and expo sdk. Previously, one could create an event using the `createEventAsync()` method with the 1st argument as **Calendar.DEFAULT** but that is no longer supported. I can use the `getCalendarsAsync()` method to get all calenders but the object I am getting back is making no sense. Some code:

```
async addReservationToCalendar(date) {
    await this.obtainCalendarPermission();
    console.log(Calendar.getCalendarsAsync());
}
```

Someone had suggested that I could iterate through the responses to find a calendar with the **isPrimary** attribute set to true but I don't see how I achieve this. I have already gotten the permission and I am receiving the following promise as a response. 
`Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}`.
What do I need to do to set a calendar event on an android device using the expo Calendar API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a promise, you need to do like this

```
Calendar.getCalendarsAsync().then(calendars => console.log(calendars))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats a promise so either you can use then statement or async await .

So 
Or you can do

```
async addReservationToCalendar(date) {
    await this.obtainCalendarPermission();
    let result = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync();
    console.log(result,'result')
    console.log(Calendar.getCalendarsAsync());
}
```

or

```
Calendar.getCalendarsAsync().then(calendars => console.log(calendars,'calenders'))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Version 39 has an example at https://docs.expo.io/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/calendar/#usage:

```
async function getDefaultCalendarSource() {
  const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync();
  const defaultCalendars = calendars.filter(each => each.source.name === 'Default');
  return defaultCalendars[0].source;
}
```